# Не отвечает бот, хотя работал корректно пару минут назад

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('Token')

@bot.message_handler(commands = ['start'])
def main(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет!')

@bot.message_handler(commands = ['help'])
def main(chat):
    bot.send_massage(chat.chat.id, 'Нужна хелпа? звони 911')


bot.polling(none_stop = True)
```

в pyCharm у меня вообще не работает последняя строчка, в vs code вбил и все начало работать, но после 3-5 минут он перестал отвечать и вообще как-либо реагировать, где я допустил ошибку, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Если Вы действительно выводите в чат такие сообщения с нецензурной бранью - то не удивляйтесь, что Вас просто банят.

Comment: Если вы действительно думаете, что это было спецаильно, то спешу развеять ваши предрассудки. Это было лишь для меня написано, в шуточной форме. Если вы не заметили исправлений, то стоит это сделать.